# Android Gradle - Filter out variant(s) only for a specific task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I'm using Android Studio 4.2.0 and Gradle 6.7.1.

I work on an Android library project that when gets built on the release CI it builds *every* single variant even if I really need one specific variant.

I already have a `variantFilter` in place that excludes `release` builds that are not from the `production` flavor, like this:

```
android {
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release' && !names.contains("production")) {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the `install` task run, I'd like to *only* build the `productionRelease` variant.

Is it possible to filter out variants based on the Gradle task that it's been launched?
Or is it possible to filter the Gradle task graph to keep only the `install` task from the `productionRelease` variant?

I've tried many configuration but failed, but I know that this community will be able to provide valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to filter out variants based on the Gradle task that it's been launched?

Yes, for your case, there is a way to assemble and install the specific variant. You can try with this command :

```
./gradlew clean installProductionRelease --stacktrace --debug --info
```